# Raw Query - MYSQL ( IF ELSE inside sql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to execute a query that collects all of the data. 
So here is my condition `if` the `client_type` of a row is Corporation the query will fetch the data of `corporation field` and it will assign it to `fullname`  or `else` it will fetch the `firstname`, `lastname` and `middlename` and assign it as `fullname`. I manage to do this query. but i have an error.

```
  (SELECT SA.id,SA.sa_code,S.importer_name as name,
  CONCAT_WS(" ",(IF(C.client_type = 'Corporation',C.corporation), 
  C.firstname,' ',C.middlename,' ',C.lastname)) as fullname,
  C.client_type,C.corporation,
  CI.invoice_code,CI.created_at as invoice_date,
  SA.created_at as salesagreement_date,
  S.id as seller_id, C.id as 
  buyer_id,SA.product_id,P.unit_code,SA.purchase_price
  FROM sales_agreement SA
  LEFT JOIN charge_invoice CI ON CI.id = SA.invoice_id
  LEFT JOIN importer S ON S.id = SA.seller_id
  LEFT JOIN clients C ON C.id = SA.buyer_id
  LEFT JOIN products P ON P.id = SA.product_id
  WHERE SA.deleted = 0
  ORDER BY SA.created_at DESC
  )P
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, I would replace your call to `CONCAT_WS` with an explicit `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    SA.id,
    ...
    CASE WHEN C.client_type = 'Corporation'
         THEN C.corporation
         ELSE CONCAT_WS(' ', C.firstname, C.middlename, C.lastname) END AS fullname,
    ...
FROM sales_agreement SA
...
```

The problem with your current call to `CONCAT_WS` is that the `IF` function call does not have an else condition, and also you have a list of things wrapped in parentheses being passed as the first (and only) parameter to `CONCAT_WS`.  In addition, if you pass a space separator to `CONCAT_WS`, then you don't have to also include spaces in the call itself.  This is the whole point of `CONCAT_WS` that it handles the separator for you.

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you mate !